# Improve Angular Material performance in IE11

Tags: angular, angular-material, internet-explorer-11

I'm using Angular Material to visualize data from a SQL Server database. The mat table is create dynamically depending on how many columns and entries I get back. There can be 40, 50+ columns and 100k+ entries.

I made the option to show only a handful of columns and via a show more button show all columns. And the paginator limits the rows to 100 by default but can show up to 2.000.

While it runs fairly smooth on Firefox and Chrome, though sorting 100k+ rows or rendering 1.000 or 2.000 rows at once may take a moment, the performance is pretty bad on IE11. Even just showing the standard 100 entries and handful of rows takes some time, switching to all columns and / or more rows is painfully slow and somethings the IE just freezes completely.

I made a little simplified demo to show how it works. The mat-table is just like the one I use.

Do you know any way to improve the performance on IE11?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elm867)

Comment: Do you mean improving performance on dealing with 100k+ rows? If so, IE is not your only concern.

Comment: The requirement is that all filtering and sorting is done on the client?

Comment: Both, overall performance and performance with 100k+ or more rows. What do you mean by not the only concern?
Everything should be done on the client side.

Comment: Internet Explorer is dead, it will never get faster and 100K rows is a lot of data to manipulate client-side regardless.

Comment: Why does everything have to be done on client side?

Comment: It doesn't strictly have to be. But I was under the impression that client performance doesn't cost while server performance does. The more people access the site at once the more the server has to do and slows down, right?

IE11 isn't my choice either but in a corporate environment it's still often used and that's what the site caters to.

Comment: @suckerp yes and no... it really depends. In most cases servers are very robust in comparison to client resources... and more often than not, severely over spec'd without proper baselines. I have often found the serve side to be better equipped to handle heavy processing/pre-formatting of data etc. prior to serving it up to the client side. 9 times out of 10, servers in corporate/enterprise environments are a waste of resources in my opinion, and often times are idle in terms of server load.

Comment: @Marshal It's a virtual Windows Server 2016 with just 8 GB RAM and 2 or 4 cores. So not really that oversized performance-wise in my eyes. Sure it will be idle most of the time but when several users access it at the same time it will likely be at capacity especially when more stuff should be done on the server side.

Can you give some starting points for server side data handling? The backend on the server is in ExpressJS.

Comment: It all depends on your baseline and application code. You are running the same setup as I am only I have 16GB ram.. I also have 4 vcpu's on a vsphere client. I average about 120 concurrent users, cpu averages 3-5% utilization, with occasional spike up to 78% during heavy calculations. I host IIS, API and SQL all on the same box. This is a CRM solution with Email campaign module and BI reporting module. My API is all over websocket, this is something to keep in mind, http based API has significant overhead.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a performance issue with the library per se, but rather the browser. Please review the following link, it is a performance test for CSS3 layout constructs in browsers.

> Run the link in Chrome, then run it in IE11 with the same settings and
>   you will quickly see the limitations of IE11.

https://testdrive-archive.azurewebsites.net/Performance/MazeSolver/

This is why Edge is being rebuilt on Chromium

https://www.wired.com/story/microsoft-edge-browser-chromium-internet-explorer/

Beyond this, you will need to explore server side pagination, and control of the data subset size transmitted across the wire to gain further performance when working with that kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the angular cdk which has a module for virtual scrolling: 
https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

In the demo they're actually rendering a list of 100,000 items, and it's smooth in IE11. I'm not sure if it would remain that way if it were a table with several columns like in your case. But you can at least give it a try.