# Angular 7 and material rendering not properly in IE11

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating project using angular and material. In my project am using material table forms and accordion. Everything working properly in chrome and edge browser but only problem in IE11.

Css is not properly rendering.when i click somewhere then it renders. Below is the screenshot of ie11

[image]

I have added all polyfills and tries everything but no success..

```
# For IE 9-11 support, please remove 'not' from the last line of the file and adjust as needed

> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11
```

added this as well..

Comment: did you got chance to check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55346182/2763709

Answer (score 0):

The Angular Components team supports the most recent two versions of all major browsers: Chrome (including Android), Firefox, Safari (including iOS), and IE11 / Edge. IE 10 is no longer supported. Edge seems to work well with material, but IE 11 still has some discrepancies.Get around these layout issues by simply adding a few CSS rules to elements that aren't displaying correctly .But make sure these changes won't affect the styles in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This issue due to flex property. Flex having issue with Internet browser.

I have override d-flex class and issue has been fixed.